# How to adding new section in INI file using TJvAppIniFileStorage

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, dbexpress, jedi, jvcl

I have a database application project written in Delphi XE and connected to MySQL Database using dbExpress. I use JVCL grid Components to show the records from the Dataset. It will be more efficiently if I can use another JVCL Components to do the FormStorage.

I've been suggested to use [**`TJvFormStorage`**](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help%3aTJvFormStorage) and [**`TJvAppIniFileStorage`**](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help%3aTJvAppIniFileStorage) for form storage. I have many forms on this project so I need to adding new section in my INI file to store the form size values but I don't know how to do that using TJvAppIniFileStorage.

The TJvAppIniFileStorage is just providing the DefaultSection() method which means it's just can modify and write into one section only which declared as the default.

Anyone can describe to me how to adding new section using the JVCL's TJvAppIniFileStorage?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the [TJvFormStorage](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help%3aTJvFormStorage) instance the one that determines in which *path* of the *abstract storage* to put the data about this form, with the value of the [`AppStoragePath`](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help%3aTJvFormPlacement.AppStoragePath) property.

You can use the special value `'%FORM_NAME%'` to determine that path automatically at run-time. The `'%FORM_NAME%'` is changed for the real `.Name` property of the form where the component is located, or if it is a frame, a dot list of the frame chain up to the form containing it. That way you can have different instances of the same class saving the info to different *paths*.

When you're using a [TJvAppIniFileStorage](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help%3aTJvAppIniFileStorage) instance as the data storage backed to save the form data to a INI file, that *path* is equivalent to the *INI section* where the information is stored.

In other words, if you want to store the info of your form in a section called 'MyForm', set that value to the `AppStoragePath` property of the `TjvFormStorage` instance in that form.

Comment: Thanks a lot jachguate! I've been try this method and it's worked correctly!

Answer (score 0):

Use the Source, Luke! ;)
My guess is: It uses Parent.Name or Parent.ClassName to store parameters.
Another point: take in mind several monitors on user's computer. Almost no app takes in mind this case.